# How can I write a regex for the given multiple numbers in a sentence?

Tags: java, regex

Here I have to return true or false if my 2 digits (can be anything) found in a number not seperated by white spaces

here 2 digits (1 and 3) are present in two different numbers(8913011, 12) and it is returning true . This is wrong scenario

```
String styy = "12 46499 8913011";
//             ^           ^
boolean contains = styy.matches("(.*\\b[0-9]*?(1[0-9]*?3|3[0-9]*?1)[0-9]*?\\b.*?)");
System.out.println(contains);
```

I want to search these two digits (1 and 3) two be present in a single number like this 4153

```
String styy = "4153 245 345"
//              ^ ^
```

In the above string 2 digits are present in a single number.

Comment: Are `**` part of actual input or you just wanted to make `1` and `3` bold?

Comment: mm, i really don't get you, can you please provide more examples?

Comment: jus want to make bold

Comment: Please don't do that -- you can see off the bat that the code formatting of the site does not make code bold, and so should have edited and removed that before posting (the site editor will show you what your post will look like *before* you post it). Please do it now, not unless you want to confuse folks.

Comment: Why do you think that a regex would be the best solution for that?

Comment: is your input `[1, 3]` or `"13"` or `13`?

Comment: I suspect what you want to achieve, but don't want to put my time in writing explanation of solution which may not be what you really want. So to get answers quicker take your time and provide more examples where you will explain what results you want, and what corner cases you want to avoid.

Comment: This is a request for free work. Please get into the habit of always making an attempt before asking volunteers to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

BOTH 3 and 1 in a set of digits

in you code, this should return true if any set of numbers in the string passed in contain both digits 1 and 3

```
boolean contains = styy.matches("\\d*1(\\d*)3\\d*|\\d*3(\\d*)1\\d*");

Short Description:
  any digits before a 1, any digits between a 3 and any digits after it
OR
  any digits before a 3, any digits between a 1 and any digits after it
```

Comment: What's with all the parenthesis?

Comment: Removed Parenthese. but would return the whole number if it contained both 3 and 1.  (\d*1(\d*)3\d*)|(\d*3(\d*)1\d*)

Comment: Splitting the string so you can get which number has both 1 and 3 , but you can test the whole string if any number in it has both 1 and 3

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify (which I highly recommend, justdumping a regex without explanation is not very helpful). Don't add comments: sometimes comments are not shown automatically, and it makes your answer much harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

How about using 2 positive lookaheads?

```
boolean contains = styy.matches(".*\\b(?=\\d*1)(?=\\d*3)(\\d+).*");
```